# Vuetify data-table pagination acting weird, can't see button or choose the items per page

Tags: vuetify.js

This is what it looks like

[image]

this is what it should look like according to vuetify data table examples

[image]

I'm not sure what happened I did it the same way as the example, this is the code where the data table is

```
<v-card>
    <v-card-title>
        <v-text-field
            v-model="search"
            label="Buscar"
            single-line
            dense
            hide-details
        ></v-text-field>
    </v-card-title>
    <v-data-table
        :headers="headers"
        :items="tableData"
        :items-per-page="itemsPerPage"
        :search="search"
        class="elevation-1">
        <template v-slot:item.action="{ item }">
            <el-button-group>
                <el-button
                    type="danger"
                    size="small"
                    plain
                    @click="edit(item)">
                    <i class="el-icon-edit"></i>
                </el-button>
                <el-button
                    type="danger"
                    plain
                    size="small"
                    @click="remove(item)">
                    <i class="el-icon-delete"></i>
                </el-button>
            </el-button-group>
        </template>
    </v-data-table>
</v-card>
```

other relevant data from the vue.js script

```
search: '',
itemsPerPage: 5,
headers: [
    {
        text: 'Nombre',
        align: 'left',
        sortable: false,
        value: 'name',
    },
    {
        text: 'Acciones',
        align: 'right',
        value: 'action',
        sortable: false
    },
],
tableData: [],
```

This might also be important, I'm using element-ui everywhere else but vuetify for the table

Comment: Did you ever get an answer for this? I am experiencing the same thing.

Comment: @Bean0341 look at my answer, that's what I ended up with

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try

```
<v-data-table
    :no-data-text="no_data"
    :headers="headers"
    :items="courses"
    :items-per-page="itemsPerPage"
    :search="search"
    hide-default-footer
    :page.sync="page"
    @page-count="pageCount = $event">                        
</v-data-table>
<template>
    <v-pagination
        v-model="page"
        :length="pageCount"
        next-icon='fas fa-angle-right'
        prev-icon='fas fa-angle-left'
    ></v-pagination>
</template>
```

//data

```
page: 1,
pageCount: 0,
itemsPerPage: 6,
courses: [],
```